# Python handling exceptions while reading JSON files

Tags: python, json

I include `try... except...` when loading my JSON file. My code is:

```
with open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8') as r:
   try:
     j = json.load(r)
   except:
     j = json.loads('['+r.read().replace('}{','},{')+']')[0]

   print(j)
```

However, `j` from `except` side never get read through. If I run the `except` code separately, I can print j with no problem.

**Update**:

For JSON fails to run `json.load(r)`, it gives an error message `Extra data: line 1 column 106362 (char 106361)`. In this case, I have to 'modify' the file little bit by passing JSON to the `except` part. However, `print(j)` returns an empty list `[]` instead of the real JSON.

I'm new to Python, just wondering if anyone has ideas on what should I do to make `try...except...` work properly?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please show a snippet of the file. Picking JSON apart like that is not good practice at all. I suspect I know the problem but I can't say without seeing it

Comment: If it's a valid json file, then the except wouldn't get triggered. Does the print(j) get called?

Comment: @alex067 That's not part of the exepction

Comment: Please provide an example of how the file looks like so that we can see what is the issye

Comment: If I understand correctly, both statements work fine when you cann them separately, but when you call it in this way, the except statement doesn't evaluate and j is not set. My guess is, that whenever an exception occurs in a context manager (in the with statement), it closes the resource, which is why it isn't able to read r.

Comment: @schilli a context manager won't call `__exit__` until the with block is exited

Comment: @schilli no, you are free to handle exceptions as you wish within the context manager. I suspect the second attempt at `j` also fails

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. It still isn't clear to me what behavior you are *expecting*.

Comment: @roganjosh or the try block never throws an exception.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, then I really am confused because I thought the issue was never reaching `print(j)`. Can't even guess at the issue without it I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The try statement `j = json.load(r)` implicitly reads the file moving the file's cursor to the end. This means reading the file again outputs an empty string, since the cursor is already at the end of the file.

Hence, the solution would be to reset the cursor using `seek(0)`:

```
with open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8') as r:
    try:
        j = json.load(r)
    except:
        r.seek(0)
        j = json.loads('['+r.read().replace('}{','},{')+']')[0]

print(j)
```

It also took me some debugging effort, but with a proper debugging tool in any IDE, you could see the file r was empty, when entering the except statement.